# Converting between bytes and interpretable string

Tags: rust

I am trying to convert a sha1 hash `info_hash` into a string format that can be used in an BitTorrent tracker announce URL. I know how to get the correct url, but I am unsatisfied with the use of "unsafe" code and I do not understand why `println!("{}", h)` shows `��9��(�l�[�����ۨζ` and not `%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6`.

```
use url::Url;

fn main() {
    let h: [u8; 20] = [216, 247, 57, 206, 195, 40, 149, 108, 204, 91, 191, 31, 134, 217, 253, 207, 219, 168, 206, 182];
    let h: &str = unsafe {
        std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&h)
    };
    
    println!("{}", h); // this shows ��9��(�l�[�����ۨζ
    
    let url = Url::parse_with_params("http://bttracker.org:6969/test",
                                 &[
                                    ("info_hash", h),
                                 ]).unwrap().to_string();
    
    println!("{}", url); // this shows the correct string format of info_hash
    
    // this causes panic (?)
    //assert_eq!(h, "%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6");
}
```

output:

```
��9��(�l�[�����ۨζ
http://bttracker.org:6969/test?info_hash=%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7475436d26b11af4ee8e2b25dd8772a4)

How do I convert the 20-byte array `h: [u8; 20]` into the string `"%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6"` without using unsafe?

Comment: why are you doing `from_utf8_unchecked` - I'd bet you have an invalid utf8 string

Comment: @DanielA.White [They do](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07a4bf40284e89820efb2d4c72ecc485).

Comment: It looks like you don't want a string representation because those aren't actually characters, you probably want your binary data as a url-encoded string, so I'd suggest a crate like [urlencoding](https://crates.io/crates/urlencoding) to handle that for you

Comment: is encoding as base64 or hex permissible?

Comment: The url-encoded string or "percent encoding" is the format I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to encode binary data into a "readable" format. What you see is called "percent encoding" or "URL encoding" <sup>[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)</sup> which writes invalid characters as `%XX`. The [url](https://crates.io/crates/url/) crate uses the [percent-encoding](https://crates.io/crates/percent-encoding) crate under the hood:

```
use percent_encoding::{NON_ALPHANUMERIC, percent_encode}; // 2.1.0

fn main() {
    let h: [u8; 20] = [216, 247, 57, 206, 195, 40, 149, 108, 204, 91, 191, 31, 134, 217, 253, 207, 219, 168, 206, 182];
    
    println!("{}", percent_encode(&h, NON_ALPHANUMERIC));
}
```

```
%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6
```

Comment: Thanks, "percent encoding" is the correct format. Do I need to use the percent-encoding crate to create the intermediary string representation for `h: [u8; 20]`? Or can I go directly from `h: [u8; 20]` to `http://bttracker.org:6969/test?h=%D8%F79%CE%C3%28%95l%CC%5B%BF%1F%86%D9%FD%CF%DB%A8%CE%B6` with the url crate?

Comment: I can see [an example](https://docs.rs/url/latest/url/struct.Url.html#method.query_pairs_mut) in the documentation for the url crate for creating url-encoded strings, but the strings they use `"\u{00C9}t\u{00E9}+hiver"` are already encoded and I can't find any examples were they go from raw bytes.

Comment: I looked around and found [this issue](https://github.com/servo/rust-url/issues/219) which sounds like binary-encoding is not available as part of the crate's api (conveniently, the topic of the issue is also bittorrent related)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, although it seems as if the url crate still will not render the url correctly with `Url::parse_with_params` when using the the intermediary string representation from `percent_encode`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6826258c86e3d936eea548a15f9c0bd6 . The `println!` is correct as noted in your code snippet, but I need it as an url for the end product. Is there any other way to go about this than to use `let h: &str = unsafe { std::str::from_utf8_unchecked(&h) };` (which creates an invalid utf-8 string) ?

Comment: An option would be to construct the query string manually and set it with [`.set_query()`](https://docs.rs/url/2.2.2/url/struct.Url.html#method.set_query): [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fff64388a527e044f8f76f68583907af)